# Get email notifications of pushes to a Git repo in IBM Bluemix DevOps Services

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, devops

I've got a Git repo on hub.jazz.net.  Is there a feature to email me whenever someone pushes changes to that repo?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, DevOps Services does not have this feature. You can use the Build and Deploy pipeline to trigger a stage that can run a script or call a website that can send you an email.

Answer (score 0):

If your project on hub.jazz.net is a github repo (github.com or github.ibm.com) you should be able to do that. If it is not, you can go to the opions section of your project and update it to use a github repo instead. Just make sure you have a clone of your repo first so you can populate your new repo with your existing code.